# How do I make a table element to horizontally overflow it's parent container?

Tags: html, css

How do I make a table element to horizontally overflow it's parent container?
I would like to avoid setting table width, since it should be sum of the columns.

I'm trying to set columns widths, but as soon as they reach parents width, they does not grow anymore.

Following snippet demonstrates two tables with different column widths, but they are both rendered equally. The second table should actually overflow the parent.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

td,
th {
  border: solid 1px red;
  text-align: center
}

#table1 col {
  width: 100px
}

#table2 col {
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table id="table1">
    <colgroup>
      <col /><col /><col />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table id="table2">
    <colgroup>
      <col /><col /><col />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add width to table , try to add

```
width: max-content;
```

to table

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: max-content;
}
```

Comment: you can use   width: max-content; in table

Answer (score 1):

just set an `overflow` to `overflow-x` property which will allow table to overflow in width and thereafter set the `width`of table

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  background: #ccc;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: solid 1px red;
  text-align: center;
}

#table1 col {
  width: 100px;
}

#table2 col {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table id="table1">
    <colgroup>
      <col />
      <col />
      <col />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table id="table2">
    <colgroup>
      <col />
      <col />
      <col />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It's the same problem as with the other answers. How do I make the table smaller than parent, when the columns width is e.g. 3x80px and parent is 300px

Answer (score 0):

The CSS property `table-layout: fixed` will only really apply if you set a width to your table. This can also be `width: 100%`. Also, remove `overflow: auto` from your parent element's class, unless you want horizontal scrollbars.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: But I don't want the table to stretch to parent's width (100%), when the parent is wider that sum of the columns.

Comment: Then it might be an idea to partially separate the CSS for them, and use `#table1 { table-layout: auto; }` (no width property) and `#table2 { table-layout:fixed;width:100%; }`, and alter the table CSS just like you alter the column width.